# Unable to incorporate birth pulses in a SIR model using deSolve

Tags: r

I am working on a [SIR model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compartmental_models_in_epidemiology#The_SIR_model) with birth pulses, using `deSolve` package. With the following code, I expected birth pulses at time step 0, 12 and 24, but the output reveals that there are no birth pulses-actually no births at all!

```
library(deSolve); library(ggplot2)   
SIR <- function (times,x,parameters) {
          SL = x[1]
          IL = x[2]
          RL = x[3]
          NL = x[4]
          if (IL<0) IL=0
          with(as.list(c(x,parameters)), {
            npopL <- SL + IL + RL
            dSL <- -(betaL*SL*IL/npopL) - ((b + (.5*(a-b)*npopL/kl))*SL) + ((((.918*round(cos(2%%((times%%12)+2)))))*(SL+RL)))
            dIL <- +(betaL*SL*IL/npopL) - gamma*IL - (b+0.015)*IL
            dRL <- +gamma*IL - b*RL
            dNL <- +dSL + dIL + dRL
            out <- c(dSL,dIL,dRL,dNL)
            list(out)
          })
        }
times <- seq(1,24, by = 1)
parameters <- c(betaL = 0.9, gamma = 0.3, a= 0.0765, b = 0.06,kl = 50)
init <- c(SL=50,IL=0,RL=0,NL=50)
out <- as.data.frame(ode(y = init, times = times, func = SIR, parms = parameters))
mydata1 <- data.frame(Period=rep((1:length(out$SL)),4),Population = c(out$SL,out$IL,out$RL,out$NL),Indicator=rep(c("SusceptibleL","InfectedL","RecoveredL","TotalL"),each=length(out$SL)))
p1 = ggplot(mydata1,aes(x=Period,y=Population, group=Indicator))
f1 = p1+geom_line(aes(colour = Indicator))
f1
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Perhaps you could start by explaining *why* you expect 'birth pulses'.  Then examine both the output of your `SIR` and of `ode` applied to that to see if, at each step, you are getting the values you expect.

Comment: It's not clear where your birth pulses are happening in your model.  I can guess but you ought to give sufficient details. If you need discrete events in this type of model you should have a look at `events` or maybe  `forcings` in package `deSolve`.

Comment: @Bhas In my function SIR, in dSL, the last part is the birth pulse [+ ((((.918*round(cos(2%%((times%%12)+2)))))*(SL+RL)))]-as only at time 0, 12 and 24 the value of round(cos(2%%((times%%12)+2))) is 1, and therefore .918*(SL+RL) should be added as birth pulse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(deSolve); library(ggplot2)
```

I'm having a go at modifying your model since I think it can be simplified.
There is no need to use `npopL` since you have variable `NL`which is what you need.

```
SIR <- function (times,x,parms) {
  SL = x[1]
  IL = x[2]
  RL = x[3]
  NL = x[4]
  if (IL<0) IL=0
  # with(as.list(c(x,parameters)), {
  with(as.list(c(x,parms)), {
    dSL <- -(betaL*SL*IL/NL) - ((b + (.5*(a-b)*NL/kl))*SL) 
    dIL <- +(betaL*SL*IL/NL) - gamma*IL - (b+0.015)*IL
    dRL <- +gamma*IL - b*RL
    dNL <- +dSL + dIL + dRL
    out <- c(dSL,dIL,dRL,dNL)
    list(out)
  })
}
```

As I said in my comment have a look at `events` in the documentation of package `deSolve`.
So create an event function for your birth pulses (where does this come from??) where I have changed the birth pulse to a fraction of total population (`NL`).

```
eventfun <- function(t, y, parms){
  with (as.list(c(y,parms)),{
    SL <- SL + .1*round(cos(2%%((t%%12)+2)))*NL
    return(c(SL,IL,RL,NL))
  })
}
```

This changes `SL` at discrete times and that is the event: birth pulse.

The rest of your code doesn't really need modification but I'm assumning that `ode` passes `parms` literally, so I changed `parameters` in your function to `parms`.

```
times <- seq(1,24, by = 1)
parameters <- c(betaL = 0.9, gamma = 0.3, a= 0.0765, b = 0.06,kl = 50)
init <- c(SL=50,IL=0,RL=0,NL=50)
out <- as.data.frame(ode(y = init, times = times, func = SIR, parms = parameters,    events=list(func=eventfun,time=times))
                )
mydata1 <- data.frame(Period=rep((1:length(out$SL)),4),Population =  c(out$SL,out$IL,out$RL,out$NL),
                   Indicator=rep(c("SusceptibleL","InfectedL","RecoveredL","TotalL"),each=length(out$SL)))
p1 = ggplot(mydata1,aes(x=Period,y=Population, group=Indicator))
f1 = p1+geom_line(aes(colour = Indicator))
f1
```

I find the results rather weird.
It's up to you to find a sensible set of parameters and to correct any further errors.

Comment: This works! The results definitely make sense now. You asked about the birth pulses- in most of the systems that I study, births do not occur year-round. Most species have seasonal breeding, i.e. all the reproducing females breed seasonally. From a disease ecology perspective, such birth pulses usually mean an increase in the proportion of susceptible individuals.